# windows form Notify Icon Not working properly

Tags: c#

notify icon disappears after 2 or 3 seconds and i have to restart the application

I have tried this code but not working properly

```
 
    private void Frm_Dashboard_Resize_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
            {
                Hide();
                notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
            }
        }
```

private void notifyIcon_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

ShowInTaskbar = true;
        notifyIcon1.Visible = false;
        WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
    }

Comment: You have to compete with all the other notification icons that want to be displayed in the limited amount of space that is available.  If you don't tell Windows that you're special then you get teleported into the "hidden icons" popup.  So go look there first before assuming your app crashed.  And no, you can't write code to become special, it is completely in control of the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not [showing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.show?view=netframework-4.8) the form in the `NotifyIcon` double click event.

Change your code to -

```
private void notifyIcon_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

        Show(); //display the form
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        notifyIcon1.Visible = false;
    }
```

Also, look at the **Remarks** section of the [ShowBalloonTip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.showballoontip?view=netframework-4.8) method